# Java Catch Block Without Try block is possible as I am throwing the Exception From a different class

Tags: java, exception

Java Catch Block Without Try block is possible as I am throwing the Exception From a different class. If it is not possible then how I can determine which type of exception is it as from the previous class I am Just throwing the Exception e

Comment: Stop describing code, write it and show it.

Comment: You need to use an [mcve] for this question. If you don't have a `try`, where that exception is coming from ? Without a `try`, you can't "catch" an exception that is thrown at some point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions Got the solution but without reading the book to learn Java . And Also without referring the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine whitch exception it is, you can check it like

```
if(e instanceof IOException)
{

}
```

But why you dont use try-catch block?

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it helped me.

Comment: I am having multiple classes in my project so i want to create a class that will identify the type of exception that has been thrown by the other exiting classes.